# How to find specific string from namespace using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem finding a specific string from the namespace `App\Models\Wordpress\Wordpress`. I want to get the last string `WordPress`, is there any way to find this?

Comment: Try this `$word = substr("App\Models\Wordpress\Wordpress", strrpos("App\Models\Wordpress\Wordpress" , '\\'));` !!

Comment: [basename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) and maybe [_ _NAMESPACE_ _](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.nsconstants.php)

Comment: @Maraboc , thanks for your quick solution but the output is " \Wordpress " i need "Wordpress"

Comment: My mistake if you needed some day you can use it like this `$word = substr("App\Models\Wordpress\Wordpress", strrpos("App\Models\Wordpress\Wordpress" , '\\')+1);` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a dynamic namespace, you can use the [magic constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) `__NAMESPACE__`:

```
$arr = explode("\\", __NAMESPACE__);
$last = end($arr);
```

Comment: thanks for your nice solution :), you've saved my day !

Answer (score 1):

You can use `explode` to split the string by a particular character ("\" in this case) and then get the final entry.

```
$string = "App\Models\Wordpress\Wordpress";
$remove="\\";
$pieces = explode($remove, $string);
$last_word = array_pop($pieces);
echo $last_word;
```